# Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined - reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm a beginner at `react.js`.

I got this error:

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

full error output in my browser chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a
>   function, not undefined
>       at _inherits (bundle.js:21166)
>       at bundle.js:21172
>       at Object.184.react (bundle.js:21196)
>       at s (bundle.js:1)
>       at e (bundle.js:1)
>       at bundle.js:1

my codes:

```
const React=require('react');
const ReactDom=require('react-dom');

class App extends React .component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                < Header />,
                < Main />,
                < Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Header extends React .component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Header>
                <nav>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </nav>
            </Header>
        );
    }
}


class Main extends React .component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p> text 1</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Footer extends React .component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h2>Footer</h2>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom .renderToStaticMarkup (<App /> ,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should change `React.component`  to `React.Component` capital C.
 e.g-`class main extends React.Component`. In addition to that, remove the space between `React.` and `Component`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're extending the classes wrong.
 It should be React.**C**omponent,
 not React.**c**omponent

Answer (score 0):

for me it occurred because of circular dependencies on static member (typescript).
for example

B :
   import A from './B'

let x=A.staticValue

A :
   import B from './A'
   class A {
       static staticValue
   }